# How to remove WindowManager view from screen?

Tags: android, window-managers

I used

```
 ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(view);
```

but it didn't work..view is still showing on the screen.
so how to remove WindowManager view from screen?

i Created it like this

```
public void create()
{
    windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);


    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    layoutParams.x = 265;
    layoutParams.y = height;
    layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.ad_dialog, null);
    Button bttnOk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bttn_ok);
    Button bttnCancel =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bttn_cancel);
    bttnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    bttnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me for solution? Thank you

Answer (score -2):

```
windowManager.removeViewImmediate(view);
```

Make sure you added that view before or it will crash your app